# Application usage statistics

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a C#/WPF application having various screens.
I need to know how much time each user spends on a screen.
What are the options to achieve this functionality please?

Also,I need to be able to log name of the the last screen used whenever any crash occurs in the app.
I tried using DispatcherUnhandledException, but I'm not able to get the name of the screen in which exception occured.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Write code that does that. When you change to a "screen" (whatever that actually means in your code), make a note somewhere of the time and the name of the "screen". You might want to handle `App.DispatcherUnhandledException` for the crash logging part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume every "screen" has a name so you could use a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Stopwatch> screenTimes = new Dictionary<string, Stopwatch>();
```

If someone enters a "screen":

```
if(screenTimes.ContainsKey(screenName))
{
    screenTimes[screenName].Start();
}
else
{
    var newStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    screenTimes[screenName] = newStopwatch;
}
```

We add a new key to the dictionary and start a `Stopwatch` for this screen.
Now, if the users leaves the screen, stop the watch.

```
if(screenTimes.ContainsKey(screenName))
{
    screenTimes[screenName].Stop();
}
```

If you want to retrieve the times, you can use `foreach` or again, with the indexer. The `Stopwatch` exposes the elapsed time as `TimeSpan` via the `Elapsed` property. Here is the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks.How do I know if the user has switched to screen B from screen A?I mean how do I capture the switch event in screen A so that I can stop the stopwatch.?

Comment: I don't know the architecture of your application. Are the screens and instance of `Window`?